# How to count array duplicate elements in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

**in MongoDB data has the following prepare aggregate function 1**

```
{"_id" : { "monthDate":"04-03-2020"}, "Job" : [ "Designer","Tester","Designer"]} 
{"_id" : { "monthDate":"14-03-2020"}, "Job" : [ "Designer","Tester","Tester"]} 
{"_id" : { "monthDate":"24-03-2020"}, "Job" : [ "Developer","Manager"]} 
{"_id" : { "monthDate":"25-03-2020"}, "Job" : [ "Developer","Developer","Developer"]}
```

**I need the following output**

```
{"_id" : { "monthDate":"04-03-2020"}, "Job" : [ "Designer":2,"Tester":1]} 
{"_id" : { "monthDate":"14-03-2020"}, "Job" : [ "Designer":1,"Tester":2]} 
{"_id" : { "monthDate":"24-03-2020"}, "Job" : [ "Developer":1,"Manager":1]} 
{"_id" : { "monthDate":"25-03-2020"}, "Job" : [ "Developer":3]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$setUnion` will get unique array from `Job` array
- `$map` to iterate loop of unique array from above operation
- `$filter` to get matching tag from main `Job` array and `$size` will get count of total matching tags from filter
- `$arrayToObject` convert k(key) and v(value) format to object format

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      Job: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: { $setUnion: "$Job" },
            as: "j",
            in: {
              k: "$$j",
              v: {
                $size: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$Job",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$this", "$$j"] }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9XLZrVB-iiT)